# MVVM и несколько ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Здравствуйте.
В данный момент я осваиваю WPF и MVVM. Недавно у меня возник вопрос, на который я пока не смог найти ответ. Суть проблемы в следующем:

У меня имеется окно, в котором присутствует ComboBox. В нем пользователь выбирает нужную ему операцию. Значения ComboBox - это элементы enum Operaton, которые связаны binding ом с ItemsSource. Также имеется ListBox, отображающий выбранные пользователем объекты и несколько Button. В зависимости от выбранной в ComboBox операции, отображаемые в ListBox объекты, и команды, выполняемые  **некоторыми** кнопками меняются. При этом View остается тем же самым.

Я создал для каждой выбранной операции свой ViewModel и поместил их в качестве public свойств в главный MainViewModel. Для главного окна установил DataContext = MainViewModel. Для ListBox и кнопок изменяющих поведение 
DataContext = MainViewModel.FirstOperationViewModel.
Но как изменять этот DataContext при изменении выбранной в ComboBox операции? Мне приходит в голову два варианта:

1. Изменять с помощью обработчика событий в code behind, нарушив идею
   MVVM.
2. Сделать binding DataContextа нужных мне контролов и SelectedItem
   моего ComboBox, используя ValueConverter. Этот вариант мне кажется
   совсем сомнительным.

**В связи с этим у меня вопросы:**

1. Как грамотно реализовать данное поведение в рамкам MVVM?
2. Имеет ли смысл в данном случае придерживаться MVVM? Т.к. в некоторых
   случаях, насколько я понял, отступление от этой модели имеет смысл.
3. Может быть использовать какой-нибудь другой подход для решения этой
   задачи? Если так, то хотя бы кратко описать его.

Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы сделал вот как.

То, что вы выбираете в комбобоксе — это не `enum`, это операция, обладающая смыслом. Поэтому комбобокс нужно привязывать не к `enum` (он вообще не нужен), а к примерно такой структуре данных:

```
class Operation
{
    public string Name { get; private set; } // имя
    public ICommand AddCommand { get; private set; } // команда для кнопки Add
    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; private set; } // команда для кнопки Delete
}
```

Содержимое класса не будет меняться после конструктора, поэтому INPC можно не имплементировать.

Затем, в `MainViewModel` заводите

```
public IEnumerable<Operation> Operations { get; private set; }
public Operation CurrentOperation { get; set; } // <-- тут реализуете INPC
```

и привязываете комбобокс как

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Operations}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentOperation, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Теперь кнопки можно привязывать к текущей операции:

```
<Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding CurrentOperation.AddCommand}"/>
<Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding CurrentOperation.DeleteCommand}"/>
```

То, что при этом делать со списком (вы пишете, что он зависит от выбранной операции), зависит от того, как именно он зависит. Возможно, в каждой операции нужен свой список, или [свой фильтр для списка](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16634194/276994).

---

Да, в некоторых случаях имеет смысл отступать от строгого MVVM. Но ваш случай не так сложен, тут отступление от MVVM не должно быть необходимо.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: @Evgeniy.Nik: Пожалуйста!